# PHP get unique filename if file exists add number and retry untill get unique

Tags: php, directory

With PHP how can I catch unique filename by adding extra number at the end of path (not adding random characther like uniqid(), crypted, rand etc) , but with code program, try catch unique file name BY ADDING +1 NUMBER.

MAYBE

> ```
> in my './image_folder/' dir have this path.
> -my-path.jpg
> -my-path-1.jpg
> -my-path-2.jpg
> -my-other-path-name.jpg 
> // try to get my-path-3.jpg
> -my-path.jpeg
> -my-path-1.jpeg
> ```

```
$filename = 'my-path.jpg';
if(filename_exists('./image_folder/' . $filename  ){
/*this file name already exists in this dir. how to get my-path-3.jpg (3 is according to adding +1 number untill get unique file name */
} else {
#this file name not exists, there's no problerm here
}
```

Comment: You might need to sort the files according to file types and filename, get the lastfilename from sorted list and add 1 to that filename.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use an loop and test, if the file exists?

```
$filename = 'my-path.jpg';
$folder = './image_folder/';
$unique = $folder . $filename;
if (file_exists($unique)) {
    preg_match('~(.*)\.([^\.]+)~', $filename, $m);
    $i = 1;
    while (file_exists($unique = $folder . $m[1] . '-' . $i . '.' . $m[2])) {
        $i++;
    }
}
// now $unique contains an non existing filename
```